# CheckList Box Delphi como pegar a String do Item que esta com o checked

Tags: delphi

Estou tendo um problema de como pegar a string do CheckListBox que está selecionado. como posso resolver o problem

```
var   
 setores : array of string

    for I := 0 to auditoriaDeEPIFrm.lckCheck.Items.Count - 1 do
    begin
      if auditoriaDeEPIFrm.lckCheck.Checked then
        setores[i] := recebe a string do que esta selecionado;


    end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var
  iCont: Integer;
  sValor: string;
begin
  for iCont := 0 to CheckListBox1.Count-1 do
  begin
    if CheckListBox1.Checked[iCont] then
      sValor := CheckListBox1.Items[iCont].Trim;
  end;
end;
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Opa, Deu certo aqui.